# Store MongoDB collection on a different drive

Tags: mongodb, collections

I'm using MongoDB on a SSD, but since I'm storing quite a lot of information, storing everything on a SSD will get very expensive. Therefore I would like to store some collections of the same database on a second drive, which is a HDD.

Is this somehow possible or would you suggest something different?

Comment: Not possible. On unix, you may tune collection, index, journal, etc... directories in different paths, but no selected collections...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB can place each database inside its own directory (see the [directoryPerDB option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.directoryPerDB)).

You can then mount each directory under a different disk. Please consult your OS manual on how to do this since it depends on the OS.

Note that the granularity is per database. There is no option to do this per collection currently.